# Using Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

this is a exercise in Simmons book.. Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function defined on $[0,1]$.The moments of $f$ are the numbers $\int _0 ^1 f(x) x^n \,dx,\; n=0,1,2,\dots$.

Prove that two continuous real valued functions defined on $[0,1]$ are identical if they have the same sequence of moments

for that, I tried this..

$\int_0^ 1 f(x)x^n\,d x= \int_0^1 g(x)x^n \,d x$  for all n

$\int_0^1 [f(x)-g(x)] x^n d x = 0$

since f and g are continuous,f-g is also continuous..so by Weierstrass theorem,we get a polynomial for that f-g whose distance will be less than given epsilon...

How can I continue my argument?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are such functions, show $\int_0^1 (f-g)^2=0$.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

As David suggests, you should try to show that $\int_0^1 [f(x)-g(x)]^2\, d x = 0$.

Here's one way to proceed: let $p_n$ be a sequence of polynomials such that $p \to (f-g)$ uniformly.  Note that for each $p_n(x)$, we have
$$
\int_0^1 (f(x) - g(x))p_n(x)\,dx = 0
$$
(Why?). What can we say about the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 (f(x) - g(x))p_n(x)\,dx?
$$